# Displaying logs in Android Studio by adding code to Smali

Tags: android, logcat, smali

In a decompiled application, I am trying to insert the information output into the logcat, but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

There is a code that displays the version number in the application, when the condition changes, I get the information I need in the application, but I cannot get it in the logcat

```
.method private F()V
.locals 4

.line 2
invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/activitys/SystemUpdateActivity;->J()V

.line 3
invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/activitys/SystemUpdateActivity;->K()V

.line 4
invoke-virtual {p0}, Landroid/app/Activity;->getApplicationContext()Landroid/content/Context;

move-result-object v0

invoke-static {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/J;->a(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/J;

move-result-object v0

invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/J;->a()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0

.line 5
new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

invoke-direct {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

const v2, 0x7f0e0205

.line 6
invoke-virtual {p0, v2}, Landroid/app/Activity;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v3

invoke-virtual {v1, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

.line 7
invoke-virtual {v1, v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

.line 8
iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/activitys/SystemUpdateActivity;->z:Landroid/widget/TextView;

invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v1

invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/widget/TextView;->setText(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V

.line 9
iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/activitys/NormalActivity;->a:Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/ImibabyApp;

invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/ImibabyApp;->getCurUser()Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/beans/u;

move-result-object v0

invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/beans/u;->j()Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/beans/H;

move-result-object v0

if-nez v0, :cond_0

return-void

.line 10
:cond_0
iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/activitys/NormalActivity;->a:Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/ImibabyApp;

invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/ImibabyApp;->getCurUser()Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/beans/u;

move-result-object v0

invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/beans/u;->j()Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/beans/H;

move-result-object v0

invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/beans/H;->D()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0

invoke-static {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/utils/LogUtil;->v(Ljava/lang/String;)V
invoke-static {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/utils/LogUtil;->i(Ljava/lang/String;)V
invoke-static {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/utils/LogUtil;->d(Ljava/lang/String;)V
invoke-static {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/utils/LogUtil;->e(Ljava/lang/String;)V
invoke-static {v0}, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/utils/LogUtil;->w(Ljava/lang/String;)V

if-eqz v0, :cond_1

.line 11
invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/String;->length()I

move-result v1

const/16 v3, 0x20

if-le v1, v3, :cond_1

const/16 v1, 0xf

const/16 v3, 0x17

.line 12
invoke-virtual {v0, v1, v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->substring(II)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0

.line 13
:cond_1
new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

invoke-direct {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

.line 14
invoke-virtual {p0, v2}, Landroid/app/Activity;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v2

invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

if-eqz v0, :cond_2

.line 15
invoke-virtual {v1, v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

.line 16
:cond_2
iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/activitys/SystemUpdateActivity;->A:Landroid/widget/TextView;

invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v1

invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/widget/TextView;->setText(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V

.line 17
iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/activitys/SystemUpdateActivity;->aa:Ljava/lang/String;

if-nez v0, :cond_3

.line 18
iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/activitys/SystemUpdateActivity;->t:Landroid/widget/Button;

const/4 v1, 0x4

invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/widget/Button;->setVisibility(I)V

:cond_3
return-void
```

.end method

I have used all possible levels of log output, but none of them are displayed in the logcat. Although in the application, the string has a textual meaning.

```
    public void m11F() {
    m19J();
    m21K();
    String a = J.a(getApplicationContext()).a();
    this.f65z.setText(getString(2131624453) + a);
    if (((NormalActivity) this).a.getCurUser().j() != null) {
        String D = ((NormalActivity) this).a.getCurUser().j().D();
        LogUtil.v(D);
        LogUtil.i(D);
        LogUtil.d(D);
        LogUtil.e(D);
        LogUtil.w(D);
        if (D != null && D.length() > 32) {
            D = D.substring(15, 23);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(getString(2131624453));
        if (D != null) {
            sb.append(D);
        }
        this.f2A.setText(sb.toString());
        if (this.f28aa == null) {
            this.f59t.setVisibility(4);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be calling methods of `Lcom/xiaoxun/xun/utils/LogUtil` this is not the standard android logcat. We do not know if that method will log to logcat at all. Perhaps try invoking methods [`android.util.Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) instead?

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem `  const-string v3, "LOG"
 
 invoke-static {v3, v0}, Landroid/util/Log;->v(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V `